# how to use spark to persist data to DB/File atomically

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have a data frame that I want to persist atomically to a data base (or a csv file).
I mean by atomically :

1. If the persistence succeed : execute a bloc of code X
2. else execute the bloc Y

the problem is that the methods from the DataFrameWriter (jdbc, csv, save) used to persist data, doesn't give a feedback whether the operation had succeed or not, therefore, I couldn't know which bloc to execute.
also in the case of DB, I want to execute a roll back, if the persistence starts but it doesn't complete normally (Bloc Y) ?

Comment: you should read about delta-like

Comment: I read some of the doc of delta-lake, however, I don't see how it can be used to store data in relational db, in fact I think that it is made to store data following the ACID rules, in hdfs, s3 or ms azure storage ( which are supported until now)

Answer (score 0):

Don't think it is possible to identify the success or failure of the "persistence" stage. Because when the size of the memory exceeds your executor memory, spark either flushes it out or spill it on to disk. Either way it makes sure that the data is accessible & it tries not recompute the data.